# Haskell 2D matrix of string

Tags: string, list, haskell, matrix

How can I define a Haskell function that takes a 2D matrix of string as input and returns a 2D matrix of string as output? This is my guess

```
empty2o :: [[String], [String]] -> [[String], [String]]
```

But this gives me this error

```
code.hs:17:12: error:
    Illegal type: `[[String], [String]]'
      Perhaps you intended to use DataKinds
   |
17 | empty2o :: [[String], [String]] -> [[String], [String]]
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

code.hs:17:36: error:
    Illegal type: `[[String], [String]]'
      Perhaps you intended to use DataKinds
   |
17 | empty2o :: [[String], [String]] -> [[String], [String]]
   |                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: A 2d matrix is `[[String]]`, not `[[String], [String]]`. I am curious why you think you should define it that way?

Comment: Apart from the good answer, implementing a matrix like data type with lists is not a bright idea. There is already [`Data.Matrix`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/matrix-0.3.5.0/docs/Data-Matrix.html) for that purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well a list of `a`s is `[a]`, so a list of lists of `a`s is **`[[a]]`**. A consequence of this however is that the rows do not per se have the same length.

So you should write it as:

```
empty2o :: [[String]] -> [[String]]
```

You can compare it with Java where the concept of a 2d array does not exists either. So you create an array of arrays.

Mind that - at least conceptually - lists in Haskell are linked lists, so in order to look up the *k*-th element, it requires *O(k)* time.

In case you want to work with a matrix, there is a package [`matrix`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/matrix-0.3.5.0/docs/Data-Matrix.html) with a module `Data.Matrix` that allows you to work with 2d matrices.